# Upload files windows to linux system with wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, apache-http-server

i have linux system .it has apache server its share localhost portal webpage

some time i want to upload files to apache htdocs using windows to linux using wifi

how can i upload to specific folder in linux using windows laptop

both sides wifi enabled

using php linux Command and windows sofware

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of solutions to this problem.

First off, ignore the "wireless networking" part of the equation - its irrelevant except to the degree that it indicates machines on the same local network.

The classic solution to the problem would be to install an FTP server on the Linux box, and then upload the files using an FTP client in Windows, but there are a lot of alternatives to this, including -

Use WinSCP (or equivalent) to push the files to the Linux machine using the SSH protocol - SSH is probably already running on the server.

Install SAMBA on Linux, configure it to read and write to the htdocs directory, and then use "Windows Filesharing" to copy the files to it.

Use NFS (and get a Windows NFS client) to achieve results similar to the above with SAMBA.

Download and install a PHP script on the Linux box which will allow it to upload and download files from it - there are lots of examples of this, here is a result with [10](http://www.nilambar.net/2012/10/best-free-web-based-file-management-scripts-in-php.html) alternative scripts I picked off Google.